# Inserir dados formulario na mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um formulario extenso então separei o HTML e varias partes mas quero continuar a guardar na mesma tabela.

Exemplo:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador (Nome1, Funcao1, MedicaValidade) VALUES ('".$Nome1."','".$Funcao1."','".$MedicaValidade."')

if ($sqlinsert)
{
echo "<script>var r = confirm('Adicionar novo trabalhador?');" .
"if (r == true) {window.open('Trabalhadores2.html','_self','false');}" .
"else {window.open('Equipamentos.html','_self','false');}</script>";
 }
```

Se o utilizador confirmar quero que o inserir outro trabalhador abre mais uma pagina de formulario e quero que guarde

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhe_trabalhador (Nome2, Funcao2, MedicaValidade2) VALUES ('".$Nome2."','".$Funcao2."','".$MedicaValidade2."')

if ($sqlinsert)
{
echo "<script>var r = confirm('Adicionar novo trabalhador?');" .
"if (r == true) {window.open('Trabalhadores3.html','_self','false');}" .
"else {window.open('Equipamentos.html','_self','false');}</script>";
 }
```

É possivel ficar assim o formulario?

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não esta muito clara, caso você deseje inserir novos usuários após ter efetuado uma inserção você pode utilizar JavaScript mesmo para isso, você pode utilizar o `location.href` e tudo deve funcionar normalmente.

Caso você tenha um formulario com muitos campos, e tenha separado em vários arquivos, nesse caso você terá que utilizar `sessões` para manter os dados durante a transação das páginas, é claro você também pode criar campos `input` do tipo `hidden` e passar os dados novamente.

Tente explicar melhor seu problema e fazer perguntas mais objetivas.